# c# Нужно ли для каждого метода расширения создавать новые файлы?

Tags: c#, ооп, методы

Нужно ли для каждого метода расширения создавать новые файлы, или можно все методы писать в одном файле в одном статическом классе?

Comment: А вам как удобнее? Вообще я бы разбил по типам, для которых создаются расширения. Если концептуально интересно, то загляните в исходники Linq.

Comment: @Darl, если вопрос решен, то отметьте галочку.

Comment: Вам был дан ответ, почему вы никак не отреагировали?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ответ не дать - автор бросил вопрос на сайт и не вернулся к нему на доп. вопросы не отвечает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Класс - это новый тип, определяемый пользователем.

Для хранения данных в классе применяются поля - это переменные, определенные на уровне класса.

Класс может определять *некоторое поведение или выполняемые действия*. Для этого применяются свои методы.

Поэтому, для каждого **нового типа (класса)** необходимы **свои** методы.

А если класс расширяется, то методы модифицируются и(или) добавляются.